# Meaning of "Derive cosine of $\theta$ from $a·b$" ? (Not an native english speaker)

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

I'm currently trying to implement some vehicle physics in a game, and this obviously requires a lot of maths. However, I'm not an english native speaker, so I have trouble understanding some terms and instructions that are given to me.

In my case, this is what they asked me to do :

> Derive cosine of the rotation angle from the dot product of $a$ and $b$.

I assume that $\theta$ here is the "rotation angle" they are talking about, and $a$ and $b$ are both vectors.
But what do they mean by "Derive... from..." ? Surely they are not asking me to calculate the derivative of $\cos \theta$, because they would instruct me to calculate "$-\sin \theta$" instead.

Can anyone please enlighten me ?

Comment: The verb that means "to compute the derivative" is "to differentiate". "Derive" here means "obtain", "find".

Comment: Hint: use the cosine rule for triangles on the triangle defined by vectors $a$ and $b$.

Comment: “Deriving” is not the same as “finding the derivative.” That’s “differentiating.” To derive means to obtain something. (It has nothing to do with derivatives.)

Comment: I should have known that derive and derivatives are not the same thing. Thanks for getting me out of the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is an answer/hint already given, here is a different one, which begins in a different place and depends on the fact that the scalar product is symmetric and bilinear and is defined in such a way that $a\cdot a = |a|^2$ for any vector $a$.

Examine the triangle $OAB$ with $OA=a$ and $OB=b$ and the third side being $b-a$. Applying the cosine rule gives $$|b-a|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2-2|a||b|\cos \theta$$

Since $a.a=|a|^2$ we have $$(a-b)\cdot(a-b)=a\cdot a+b\cdot b-2|a||b|\cos \theta$$

and this reduces to $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos \theta$

This allows you to use the components with respect to a suitable (orthonormal) basis to calculate everything - it demonstrates that the two different common ways of expressing the scalar product give the same result, and enables the angle to be computed using a definition which doesn't depend on knowing the angle.

Comment: So after reading all these answers, this means all I have left to do is to calculate cos θ = (a⋅b) / (|a||b|). Am I right ?

Comment: @BenoîtLy correct

Comment: Thank you, your explanations are really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of the dot-product is given by
$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos\angle(\vec{a},\vec{b})$$

Comment: If you define the scalar product in this way, you have to show and justify a way of computing it which doesn't depend on knowing the angle.

Comment: See here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html